# Weights & Biases: 'define_metric' with Bayesian Optimization sweep

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameters, wandb

Let's say, I am trying to optimize some hyperparameters on a goal metric by maximizing it. The selected sweep method is `bayes`. Also, that goal metric is defined by `define_metric` function with a summary flag, namely `max`. Basically, on the summary table, I am logging the max value of this goal metric, instead of the last logged value.

My question is, how does the Bayesian sweep work with `define_metric` method? Does the sweep optimize on the metric by maximizing the summary value (last logged/max/min etc.) ? Or does it neglect `define_metric` and takes a global maximum value into account ?

In the training script:

```
wandb.define_metric("goal_metric", summary='max')
...
wandb.log({"goal_metric": ...
```

In the sweep configuration:

```
method:   bayes
metric:
  goal:   maximize
  name:   goal_metric
```